# Why is this function not being graphed as expected?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, graphing-functions, machine-precision

I am interested in the Rastrigin function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rastrigin_function.

I have read that the local minimums of this function occur at integer coordinates. However, when I plug this function into a grapher like Desmos, the local minimas are not showing up at integer locations (but close to them).

[image]

When I evaluate this in Wolfram Alpha, I get the same thing: the local minimas are not actually at integer coordinates, but somewhere close. Same in Python.

Why am I getting these results? Do the function's minimums not actually come at integer coordinates, am I evaluating it wrong, or could it be some sort of precision issue?

Comment: Where did you read that the local minima were at integer points?

Comment: In this paper: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/281929848_Leaders_and_Followers_-_A_New_Metaheuristic_to_Avoid_the_Bias_of_Accumulated_Information

Comment: "The optima in Rastrigin are placed at the integer coordinates of a regular grid of size one, which means that the
function has 11n optima within the search boundaries defined
above. Given a solution in this well-structured search space,
the closest (local) optimum in the attraction basin can be
easily determined by rounding each component to its nearest
integer. This information allows us to present the motivation
for conducting this research with the following experiment."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not true that the minima are at integers because of the $x^2$ term.  They are close to integers because the cosine term changes much faster than the $x^2$ term. 
 If we take the derivative we get 
$$f'(x)=2x+20\pi \sin(2\pi x)$$
The second term is $0$ at $x=1$ but the first is not.  We need to make the second term about $-2$ to get the derivative to be $0$, which does not happen at $x=1$  A first approximation for the derivative comes from 
$$2+20\pi \sin(2\pi x)=0\\
\sin (2\pi x)=\frac {-1}{10\pi}\\
x=1+\frac{-1}{20\pi^2}\\
x \approx 0.995$$
in agreement with your plot